# icecast stream html5 player audio tag

Tags: html, stream, mp3, icecast, m3u

I am having trouble getting a stream to embed with this audio tag:

`<audio controls autoplay="autoplay"><source 
   src="http://159.65.84.223:8000/stream?type=.mp3" type="audio/mp3">Your 
   browser does not support the audio element.</audio>`

should I use another code?

Thanks

Comment: The URL does not point to an existing stream. So that won't work obviously.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the correct audio link inside the [XSPF file of your stream](http://159.65.84.223:8000/00a48ebe728b.xspf) (open it as text file).

Try setting code as:

```
<audio controls autoplay="true">
<source src="http://mensajito.mx:8000/00a48ebe728b" type="audio/mp3">
</audio>
```

Test the example link below, and report if this gives a correct (playing) result:

https://jsfiddle.net/5s69pb34/

Some notes:

- Your stream link is `http://` and may not work if used inside some `https://` website.
- The `type` can be either `"audio/mp3"` or `"audio/mpeg"`. Try each type if got errors.

Comment: Be aware streams via html 5 audio can not be stopped or paused. on pause, stream audio stops, but file download continues in the background. 

This pauses 2 problems, 

1) user's phone data is still chowed even when they think they stopped or paused the stream. 
2) when user resumes, playing resumes from where they left off.